# Mysql left/inner join combination not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I am trying to list product variations with their quantities ordered, BUT ALSO show the product variations where there is no quantity ordered. So I thought it would be as simple as selecting the products and doing a left join on the orders of each product where the order is a current revision.

So I expected like this order of operations:

```
SELECT p.product_id, SUM(po.quantity) 
FROM `products` p 
LEFT JOIN `product_orders` po ON p.product_id=po.product_id 
LEFT JOIN `orders` o ON o.order_id=po.order_id AND o.is_current='1'
```

but that is getting also the quantities where the is_current is not 1
Then I thought, okay, I can just do an inner join after the left join instead like this:

```
SELECT p.product_id, SUM(po.quantity) 
FROM `products` p 
LEFT JOIN `product_orders` po ON p.product_id=po.product_id 
INNER JOIN `orders` o ON o.order_id=po.order_id AND o.is_current='1'
```

but then the products which have not been ordered yet are not being listed. I expected them to to show up as SUM(quantity) being NULL.
Can anyone see where my logic has gone wrong?
Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the only product orders that count are those where it is current then you need to find that subset *before* you do a left join to it. Otherwise if you do a left join you either get all or only those ordered as you've discovered.

So something like the following should work:

```
select p.productid, sum(po.quantity)  
from products p  
left outer join (select po.productid, po.quantity  
                       from productorders po  
                       inner join orders o on o.orderid = po.orderid and o.iscurrent = 1) po on po.productid = p.productid  
group by p.productid
```

Comment: makes sense, i will try it... one sec

Comment: No problem. You were on the right track; just needed an extra step

Answer (score 33):

While Kaj's answer is correct, it's not necessarily ideal, as MySQL tends to skip the utilization of indexes when using derived tables (sub-selects).  At least, this is my understanding.  You can continue to use your methodology of using JOINS if you place the joins within parenthesis:

```
SELECT p.product_id, SUM(po.quantity) 
FROM `products` p 
LEFT JOIN (`product_orders` po
  INNER JOIN `orders` o ON o.order_id=po.order_id AND o.is_current='1')
ON p.product_id=po.product_id;
```

Just remember that the ON clause for the LEFT JOIN needs to come after the parenthesis.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I don't use stackoverflow very often, and don't know how to put the code into its own section.

Comment: I sometimes over-look the excellent point you made regarding indexes and sub-selects. Nice explanation.

Comment: Thanks!  I do what I can...ha.

Comment: For others looking for a reference please see the MySQL documentation on [Nested Join Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-join-optimization.html)

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL will automatically create an index for a derived table.  (This is better than not having an index, but usually not as good as reformulating the query.)

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by your product id:

```
SELECT p.product_id, SUM(po.quantity) 
FROM `products` p 
LEFT JOIN `product_orders` po ON p.product_id=po.product_id 
INNER JOIN `orders` o ON o.order_id=po.order_id AND o.is_current='1'
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still only lists products that have at least quantity ordered of one (so appearing in the product_orders table)

Comment: is it working if you change back the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Yes the query then works, but i also get all the quantities for is_current!='1' then (so older revisions of the same order)